# safari iPad: disable ipad cache while its connected to mac?

Tags: safari, development

i read online recently that there is a way to disable safari's cache on the iPad using the mac's safari developers tools as long as the iPad is connected via usb.

I can't find the article i was reading but is this possible? If so please provide steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this on stack overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9218123/how-to-disable-cache-on-ios-safari)

[@Collin Allen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/41728/collin-allen) wrote: "I just stumbled across a way to disable cache in Safari on iOS:

**iOS**

1. Open Settings
2. Navigate to Safari > Advanced
3. Enable Web Inspector
4. Switch back to Safari and load a web page

**Desktop**

1. Open Safari
2. Navigate to Safari > Preferences > Advanced tab
3. Enable the Develop menu
4. In the Develop menu, select Your iOS Device Name > The Page You Want
   to Debug
5. Press Command-Shift-R to reload while disabling cache
6. Bonus: This is a full Web Inspector on your computer inspecting a
   page on your iOS device

If you want something more permanent, you'll either have to go the proxy route or make a UIWebView/WKWebView wrapper app that disables caching."

Answer (score 2):

By connecting your device to your Mac, you can use Safari Developer Tools to open the JavaScript console for the WebView on your iPad. Therefore, you can use the following JavaScript to refresh the page which will ignore the cache:

```
window.location.reload(true)
```

Comment: I'll give this a try @grgarside. Thanks & I'll be sure to select an answer once I find the best solution.